# How to open a new mail with Lotus c# (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, email, lotus

I am currently developing a small application in C# . Net allowing to perform different tasks, but here in one of my tasks I have to open a new default mail from Lotus. However I don’t find much documentation on it, so I’m a little lost and that’s why I’m in your hands :/
So I just need to be able to open Lotus with a new default email.
Thank in advance ;)

Comment: You want to open up a new email account or open up the Lotus notes application / website connected to a mail account ?

Comment: I just want to run the app and create(not send, just open) a new email with already the object in it for example ;)

Comment: Ok answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public void ComposeMemo(String sendto, String subject, String body)
    {
        //BLOC1 instantiate a Notes session and workspace
        Type NotesSession = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesSession");
         Type NotesUIWorkspace = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace");
         Object sess = Activator.CreateInstance(NotesSession);
         Object ws = Activator.CreateInstance(NotesUIWorkspace);

        //BLOC2 open current user's mail file
        String mailServer = (String)NotesSession.InvokeMember("GetEnvironmentString", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, sess, new Object[] { "MailServer", true });
        String mailFile = (String)NotesSession.InvokeMember("GetEnvironmentString", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, sess, new Object[] { "MailFile", true });
        NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("OpenDatabase", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ws, new Object[] { mailServer, mailFile });
        Object uidb = NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("GetCurrentDatabase", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ws, null);
        Object db = NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("Database", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, uidb, null);
        Type NotesDatabase = db.GetType();

        //BLOC3 compose a new memo
        Object uidoc = NotesUIWorkspace.InvokeMember("ComposeDocument", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ws, new Object[] { mailServer, mailFile, "Memo", 0, 0, true });
        Type NotesUIDocument = uidoc.GetType();
        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "EnterSendTo", sendto });
        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "Subject", subject });
        NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uidoc, new Object[] { "Body", body });

        //BLOC4 bring the Notes window to the front
        String windowTitle = (String)NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("WindowTitle", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, uidoc, null);
        Interaction.AppActivate(windowTitle);
    }
```

The BLOC1 perform, it open the application but from BLOC2 the application no longer responds but I don’t know why, more in BLOC4 the word Interaction is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the selenium web driver to access their **website** and automatically create an email account.

Manipulating the **application** it self can be quite complex you can use the .NET windows Input Simulator Nugat package to simulate user input to the application or write directly to memory using the windows API.

I don't think there is a **supported way** of doing that by Lotus.

But if you can use Gmail there is a Gmail API 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/
Use the .NET httpClient to interact with it.
And to **create a Gmail account** 
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use Lotus notes, and I have to be able to open the application and not the website or other:/
However I found a piece of code on the Internet half-running, to show you I will comment on my topic below;)